# Trying to make margins unclickable

Tags: html, css, button, margin

While making some buttons I've run into this issue where the empty spaces/margins beside the buttons are clickable, which is what I'm trying to get rid of now. I've been looking over similar posts that go over this kind of thing but I've had no luck in applying those answers to my code, and unfortunately my messing around with it hasn't helped a whole lot either. This thing is kind of driving me crazy at this point and any bit of help would be greatly appreciated :')

Here's the code itself:

```css
button {
  background-color: #edca6e;
  border: none;
  color: #523e5c;
  padding: 8px 60px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console';
  margin: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="logo" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
  <!--portfolio, about, contact, misc.-->
  <br><br><br>
  <a href="../1portfolio/portfolio.html"><button>text</button></a>
  <a href="/2aboutme/about.html"><button>text</button></a>
  <a href="#"><button style="margin:30px;">text</button></a>
  <a href="../4misc/misc.html"><button>text</button></a>
</center>
```

If anything else needs to be clarified, please let me know :)

Comment: You should never nest a `button` in an `a` tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When u wrap your button with `<a>` tag, the whole component of button will be clickable (include the margin). Although it is not practicable to use `<a>` with `<button>`, still I have a solution that you can overcome your current issue.

To make the margin not clickable, you can apply the margin in `<a>` tag and move the display attribute from `<button>` style to `<a>` style, Kindly refer to following code:

CSS:

```
  button {
     background-color: #edca6e;
     border: none;
     color: #523e5c;
     padding: 8px 60px;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 30px;
     font-family: 'Lucida Console';
     cursor: pointer;
  }
  a{
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 30px;
  }
```

HTML:

```
    <center>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="logo" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
      <!--portfolio, about, contact, misc.-->
      <br><br><br>
      <a  href="../1portfolio/portfolio.html"><button>text</button></a>
      <a  href="/2aboutme/about.html"><button>text</button></a>
      <a  href="#"><button >text</button></a>
      <a  href="../4misc/misc.html"><button>text</button></a>
    </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Margin should be moved to `a` instead of `button`. As of now, `button` has some margin, which makes `a` has some redundant space.

And yeah, you shouldn't be using `button` inside `a`. Both are clickable.